# igGrid "404 Not Found" on dataSourceURL

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

This *was* working with no problems yesterday. However, I'm unable to identify any obvious changes in my code since leaving and returning to my workstation this morning.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 controller method which returns a JsonAction object, and accepts no parameters (HttpGet). I've tested its return, and it is returning proper JSON--the same structure as with yesterday when I didn't have this issue. This does seem to rule out any possibilities on the server-side.

The call to dataBind is using a URL which looks like this:

> /Home/GetAllUsersJSON?pk=userid&_=1413996086894

The cause appears to be, from examining in Chrome, that the igGrid's client API seems to be appending (or attempting to append) a query string to the end of the dataSourceURL during dataBind(). I can't even identify the value of the second parameter (which also is nameless, seemingly just an underscore character) in any of the relevant database tables (in other words, I haven't a clue where that value comes from)--however, it does remain unchanged through each debug attempt.

I'm only using client-side (JS) to render and operate the igGrid. Here is that code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#usersgrid').igGrid({
        autoGenerateColumns: false,
        columns:    [
            { headerText: 'userid', key: 'userid', dataType: 'number' },
            { headerText: 'username', key: 'username', dataType: 'string' },
            { headerText: 'login', key: 'loginid', dataType: 'string' },
            { headerText: 'role', key: 'role', dataType: 'string' },
            { headerText: 'distributor', key: 'distributorid', dataType: 'number' },
            { headerText: 'inactive', key: 'inactive', dataType: 'boolean' },
            { headerText: 'lastupdated', key: 'lastupdated', dataType: 'date', format: 'dateTime' }
        ],
        dataSourceUrl: '/Home/GetAllUsersJSON',
        primaryKey: 'userid',
        features: [{
            name: 'Updating',
            enableAddRow: true,
            enableDeleteRow: true,
            columnSettings: [{
                columnKey: 'userid',
                editorOptions: { readonly: true, disabled: true }
            }, {
                columnKey: 'username',
                editorType: 'string',
                validation: true,
                editorOptions: { required: true }
            }, {
                columnKey: 'loginid',
                editorOptions: { readonly: true, disabled: true }
            }, {
                columnKey: 'role',
                editorType: 'string',
                validation: true,
                editorOptions: { required: true }
            }, {
                columnKey: 'distributorid',
                editorType: 'numeric',
                validation: true,
                editorOptions: { button: 'spin', minValue: 0, maxValue: 2000000, required: true }
            }, {
                columnKey: 'inactive',
                editorType: 'combo',
                editorOptions: {
                    mode: 'dropdown',
                    required: true,
                    dataSource: trueFalseValues,
                    textKey: 'text',
                    valueKey: 'value'
                }
            }, {
                columnKey: 'lastupdated',
                editorOptions: { readonly: true, disabled: true }
            }]
        } ]
    }).igGrid('dataBind');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dataSource` option instead of the `dataSourceUrl`. The `dataSourceUrl` is intended for load on demand scenarios in MVC and is not used for initial data binding. You can pass a remote url as the `dataSource` option value. The parameters that you see are the name of the primary key field and the callback to be executed when the jsonp request finishes.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434621/using-my-custom-ajax-call-for-load-on-demand-on-ighierarchical-grid